# SwiftUI Query Firebase Map where Value exist

Tags: firebase, swiftui

I am working with a SwiftUI app with a Firebase collection that has records that have a map field, with keys of roles and values of userIds, such as:

```
{
    id: 1, 
    name: Group1,
    roles: 
        President: userId1
        VicePresident: userId2
},
{
    id: 2,
    name: Group2,
    roles:
        President: userId2
        Treasurer: userId3
}
```

There are a lot more roles that I have listed, and as shown there can be different roles and users can be in roles for more than one group. I want to query my collection to find all groups that any user is in, so if I queried for userId2 then it would return both Group1 and Group2, but if I queried userId1 or userId3 then just their one respective group would return. Is there an efficient way to query my collection to achieve my desired results?